# Ограничение действия return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Этот код обрабатывает клик по элементам на сайте (меню первого уровня), в результате которого появляется новый блок (меню второго уровня, переход по ссылке остановлен return false, чтобы было видно меню второго уровня). Также, по клику вне этого всплывшего блока, он закрывается. Но дело в том, что в нём (этом появляющемся блоке) тоже есть ссылки(пункты меню второго уровня), и нужно, чтобы переход по ним работал. А второй клик по пунктам меню первого уровня тоже приводил к переходу по ссылке.

```js
$(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.overlay', function(e) {
    $('.header__bottom-hover-menu.active, .header__top, .header__bottom').removeClass('active');
    $('.header__nav-item > a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
   });
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
     var container = $(".header__bottom-hover-menu.active");
     if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
      container.removeClass('active');
      $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
     }
    }
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.header__nav-item', function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
     console.log("CLICK2");
     $('.header__bottom-hover-menu.active, .header__top, .header__bottom').removeClass('active');
     // $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
     $('.header__nav-item > a.active').removeClass('active');

     $('.header__hover-list-item.active').removeClass('active');
     $('.header__hover-tab.active').removeClass('active');

     $('.header__hover-list-item[data-tab="1"]').addClass('active');
     $('.header__hover-tab[data-tab="1"]').addClass('active');
    }

    return false;
   }, function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1150) {
     let overlay = $('.overlay');

     $('.header__bottom-hover-menu.active, .header__top, .header__bottom').removeClass('active');
     $('.header__nav-item > a.active').removeClass('active');
     overlay.removeClass('active');

     if ($(this).find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('a.submenu').addClass('active');
      $(this).find('.header__bottom-hover-menu').addClass('active');
      $('.header__top, .header__bottom').addClass('active');
      overlay.addClass('active');
     }
    }
    return false;
   });
  });
```

Comment: Какие ссылки и в каком меню?

Comment: https://dev.shonada.com
переходите смело - это сайт для разработок, просто с сертификатом не заморачивались. Главное меню, нужно, чтобы во всплывающем блоке работали ссылки.